# Report Column Based On Previous Column

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I am strugling for a long time to make a report for my client but without success, i have a database with 3 columns, item number, date, On-hand. My client wants a matrix report, (also called crosstab or pivot), which should show the daily changes of item status, namely the items that were out of stock and became in stock, and vice versa. I tried in VS report viewer but I cannot seem to grasp how to make a column in the report display info based on previous column, any help?

Comment: Did you try to create your report from a new DataTable got from a SQL SELECT command using a "Pivot" syntax?

Comment: I could be wrong, but this should be handled in the SQL Query that you feed the report: For each day (or whatever time period) identify current and prior status for each item, and perhaps also calculate a Status Changed flag.

Comment: thanks. both are a good idea, i will pursue the later. pivot is to tough, how do you generate the date list ofr the pivot

Comment: If you have SQL Server 2012+, you could use [LEAD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) or [LAG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256%28v=sql.110%29.aspx). I strongly recommend to do it on the DB Server side instead of Reporting Services. If you are not able to get the query working, I'm pretty sure that you will get good answers if you ask a question with the `sql` and `sql-server` tag, with your failed attempts.

Comment: I think you are asking for a technique that will not solve your problem.   Please post some sample data from your table, and a desired output that illustrates what you are trying to do.   It is not very clear the way it is currently posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understanding what you are asking, but it may be helpful to know that you can reference a particular cell in your matrix with this syntax:

```
ReportItems!cellname.Value
```